# Runtime error when filling value to another workbook till last row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a code to paste a name from one workbook to another and autofill but while running the code I'm getting Runtime error 9, here is the example code

```
Sub test()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim lstRow As long

workbook.open("path")
Set WB = activeworkbook

lstRow = Range("M2").End(xlDown).Row
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G3").Copy
WB3.Sheets(("I2:I") & lstRow).PasteSpecial xlpastevalue

End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing some information in your code - what sheet in `WB` you want to paste the values ?  Also, you want to paste the value in `Range("G3")` to an entire row ? the same value ?

Comment: I want to paste the value from G3 to WB. Sheets("sheet1")

Answer (score 0):

```
OPTION EXPLICIT

Sub test()    
    Dim WB As Workbook

    Set WB = workbook.open("path")
    with WB.WorkSheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "M"), .Cells(.rows.count, "M").End(xlup))
            .Offset(1, -6).Resize(.Rows.Count -1, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G3").Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know why this solution is also not working but thanks for the help